# Finding whether a system is linear and time-invariant given input x(t) and output y(t) in integral form.

Tags: fourier-transform, signal-processing

I had this question which I could not figure out myself, if you could at least guide me in it, it would be good.
The question says:
The output y(t) of a system is related to its input x(t) by

$$y(t)=\int h(t, t') x(t')dt'$$

The integral limits are from $-\infty$  to  $\infty$

How would I know if the system is linear and also time-invariant?

Comment: What is $h(t,t')$? Is it the delta function?

Comment: I think it is impulse response, not sure though.

Comment: Impulse response of what? the same system?

Comment: So the system is clearly linear, because if you were to take a linear combination of inputs, it would be the same linear combination of outputs

Comment: For time invariance, it depends on whether$h(t,t')$ is time invariant. If that's the case, then it is also time invariant

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan Actually I am not sure about the h(t,t') part myself, I said it is the impulse response of the system because h(t) was used as impulse response of the system in previous questions.